# Review audit of a question with a downvote and a close vote

Tags: support, bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/28062997) by voting to close as general computing.  Aside from the fact that I maintain I was correct (this question is quite clearly about installing general computing software, as Homebrew is not mainly a developer tool), the question had both a downvote and a close vote at the time I failed the audit (or at least *immediately* afterward when I clicked through):

[image: Screenshot showing 12 upvotes, 1 downvote]
[image: screenshot showing 1 close vote]

Aren't questions with downvotes and/or close votes [not supposed to be selected as review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/165261)?

Comment: That's a *terrible* audit, in more ways than one. Code-as-image, general computing, already had a close vote. Pah!

Comment: possibly related: [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773)

Answer (score 10):

As a guess as to the root cause, it looks like the review audit was generated substantially before it was shown to me:

[image: Timeline entry showing audit created 10 hours ago, completed 33 mins ago]

According to the timeline, the downvote came in within the past ~4 hours (i.e., it was cast on this UTC day). I'm unable to check when the close vote was cast.

I didn't leave the review up that long: I reviewed it almost immediately after it was displayed to me.  Perhaps the system is failing to clear out *existing* audit tasks when a post becomes ineligible to be used as an audit?